# change hyperlink color while other hyperlink are clicked

Tags: html, css, href

How can i change my hyperlink color back to original color when other link is clicked? the hyperlinks are targeted on the same page.

please check this  [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/9ncnrwxq/1/)

from the above example you can see that when click apple then click grape / banana.. both are become same color because (visited). How to make it only 1 color (green) when any of the links are clicked

Comment: you can use `a:active {color: green}` and keep blue on visited

Comment: You can't do this completely purely with CSS, the best you can get if you redirect the target to be the same as the clicked element. [Like so](http://jsfiddle.net/9ncnrwxq/7/), although you lose the functionality of moving to the targeted location. Otherwise you need to use JavaScript.

Answer (score 2):

You can do this using `jQuery`

```js
$('body a:link').click(function()
{
 $('body a').removeClass('active');
 $(this).addClass('active');  
});
```

```css
a:link {
    color: blue;
}

/* visited link */
a.active {
    color: green;
}

/* mouse over link */
a:hover {
    color: red;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<a class="fruit" href="#apple">apple</a></span>
<a class="fruit"  href="#grape">grape</a></span>
<a class="fruit"  href="#banana">banana</a></span>
<div style="height:500px"></div>
<a name="apple"> apple here</a>
<a name="grape"> grape here</a>
<a name="banana"> banana here</a>
```

Comment: any other method other than jquery?

Comment: I think in the CSS there is no better solution like jQuery but in the CSS `:active` and `:focus` selectors give us a limited solution.

Answer (score 1):

When you're defining all 4 states, you should define them in this order:

1. Link
2. Visited
3. Hover
4. Active

This fixes about half of your problem.

```
a:link { color: blue; }
a:visited { color: blue; }
a:hover { color: red; }
a:active { color: green; }
```

The other half, leaving the links coloured until you click something else, is harder. There's no in-built state for the previously clicked anything, so let's make one.

First, we'll need jQuery for this, so let's import it (via Google). This goes in the head of your HTML:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.4/jquery.min.js">
</script>
```

In jfiddle, you add this by selecting jQuery 2.1.4 from the dropdown on the left instead.

We can then add a class to links if they're the last clicked link by providing this JavaScript:

```
$(function(){
    $('a').click(function(){
        $('a.lastclicked').removeClass('lastclicked'); //remove class from previous link
        $(this).addClass('lastclicked'); //add class to newly clicked link
    });
});
```

Finally, let's adjust the CSS to do the colouring:

```
a:link { color: blue; }
a:visited { color: blue; }
a:hover { color: red; }
a:active { color: green; }
a.lastclicked { color: green; }
```

If you want the hover colour to be applied to the last clicked link too, then you can add this line:

```
a.lastclicked:hover { color: red; }
```

You can see all of this in action **[in a Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/L8set2xw/6/)**.

Answer (score 0):

Try this (Do copy and paste):

Test.html:-

```
<html>
 <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="style.css">
 <a class="fruit" href="#">apple</a></span>
 <a class="fruit"  href="#">grape</a></span>
 <a class="fruit"  href="#">banana</a></span>
 <div style="height:500px"></div>
 <a name="apple"> apple here</a>
 <a name="grape"> grape here</a>
 <a name="banana"> banana here</a>
</html>
```

style.css:-

```
a:link{
 color:blue;
}

a:visited{
 color:purple;
}

a:hover{
 color:orange;
}
a:focus{
color:green;
}

a:active{
 color:red;
}

a:active{
 color:yellow;
}
```